# Ubuntu does not detect connected monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi

I am using Lenovo IdeaPad Pro 5 14IMH9 with integrated GPU Intel Arc.
Ubuntu 23.10
Connected with HDMI

Tried plugging and unplugging with multiple restarts. Both update and upgrade are up to date.

xrandr shows

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 2880 x 1800, current 2880 x 1800, maximum 2880 x 1800
default connected primary 2880x1800+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   2880x1800     91.00*
```

Could anyone help me please?

Edit:

response from `xset -q`

```
$ xset -q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00001000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     on     13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  33
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Comment: try `xset -q` and tell us what it outputs in the Screen SAver: section.

Answer (score -1):

If your laptop has an additional GPU (not integrated into the processor), you should install drivers for it to make HDMI work.